# How to make part of a rig movable in Unity

Tags: modeling, unity

I'm not sure if this is a Blender issue or a Unity issue - apologies if I'm barking up the wrong tree.

My partner & I are making a simple little low-poly game; I'm making character models in Blender and he's programming in Unity. We're both new to the programs and process. We want to have NPCs turn their heads and look at the first-person camera when the player interacts with them (ie, on mouse-click), but we're not sure how to best achieve that. I know I can animate a head-turn in Blender, but that won't account for all the positions from which the player might interact with the model...unless I make a bunch of tedious animations.

Is it possible to separate the head from a rig in such a way that Unity can interact with and transform it dynamically? Ideally we'd use a LookAt function in Unity to make just the model's head turn up/down and left/right, but I don't know if or how you get that from a rigged and posed Blender model to Unity. I've been searching for the past few days and not found (or possibly not understood) any solutions to this specific situation. Any thoughts on how to achieve a targeted head-turn using a Blender model in Unity?

Comment: I think Animation Rigging is built for this kind of thing. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.animation.rigging.html (still have not had time to try it so can't elaborate :( )

Answer (score 0):

I think you have pretty much answered the question yourself. Instead of animating it in Blender you will probably have to set the transform using a lookAt Constraint or a custom script in Unity. If the head is not a separate geometry you will have to build/use a rig in blender allowing you to drive the head movement using bones. The exchange format to unity is usually FBX, which also supports rigged geometries. The bones should be visible in unity as transforms ina hierarchy.